# problem accessing odoo from ubuntu terminal 18

Tags: odoo-12

I'm trying to access odoo through commands but I get critical errors one is **odoo.modules.module: Couldn't load module web**

**odoo.modules.module: The 'odoo.addons.web' package was not installed in a way that PackageLoader understands.**

**ERROR? odoo.service.server: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.**

so I can't access odoo with the command ./odoo-bin

Do you know how I can solve the problem?

Comment: please check your addons path in .conf file

Comment: .conf.file i have addons_path = /opt/odoo/addons,/opt/odoo/odoo/addons

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must uninstall jinja2 and reinstalling with this version Jinja2==2.10.1

> pip3 uninstall jinja2

and

> pip3 install Jinja2==2.10.1

Comment: can u tell the use of jinja package

Comment: It's work for me on Odoo12, in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60879942/odoo12-couldnt-load-module-web/60880173#60880173

Comment: @PsPranav Jinja is a commonly used templating engine. Find more details: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had this issue in openerp8 with python2.7

I had updated Jinja2 version which is not supported by python2.7 version so I just degrade the version from 2.11 to 2.10 and it's work.